# Google Analytics - How do I set an _addIgnoredRef to multiple domains?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I have a network of some websites (same sites - diffrent language but some of them are using subdomains and some of them are top level domains).

I want to set *_addIgnoredRef* to all of the sites in the network to stop track referrals from my own site network but I'm not sure about the right syntax to ignore multiple domains with the *_addIgnoredRef*  tag.

Do I have to write it each domain in new line like this?

```
pageTracker._addIgnoredRef("www.website.es"); 
pageTracker._addIgnoredRef("www.website.fr"); 
pageTracker._addIgnoredRef("pt.website.com"); 
pageTracker._addIgnoredRef("ru.website.com");
```

Or maybe I should write it in a one line like this?

```
pageTracker._addIgnoredRef("www.website.es","www.website.fr","pt.website.com","ru.website.com");
```

Hope someone can help me with that - Thanks!

Comment: You should upgrade your trackingcode to universal analytics. _addIgnoreRef has been replaced by the referral exclusion list which is managed via property settings, not in the code.

Comment: I know I use the old code and I need to replace to the new one but currently It's not an option to replace it so I need to handle this issue using the code at the moment...

Comment: It's probably worth a try to use the referral exclusion list in any case - processing is switched to Universal Analytics (with some degree of compatibilty for old tracking code) and this is one of the things that might just work.